# Setting the value of an index of a string array to that of an item within an Enumerable array by using a "foreach" statement.

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable

Is this the best way to set each item of a string array to that of an Enumerable array? I came up with this approach on my own, I tried to use my google-foo but couldn't really come up with coherent sentences to describe what i'm trying to do here..

```
string[] adapterDesc = new string[] {};
int i = 0;
foreach(NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
{
    adapterDesc[i] = adapter.Description;
    i++;
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that code will fail with an `IndexOutOfRange` exception because you have declared an array of strings that could contain zero elements.
So when you try to set the first element it will crash.

Instead you could use a List where you can add elements dynamically

```
List<string> adapterDesc = new List<string>();
foreach(NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
{
    adapterDesc.Add(adapter.Description);
}
...
```

A List is more flexible than an array because you don't have to know before the size of the array and you could still use it like it was an array

```
for(int x = 0; x < adapterDesc; x++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(adapterDesc[x]);
}
```

If you want to use Linq then you could even reduce your code to a single line with

```
string[] adapterDesc = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                              .Select(ni => ni.Description)
                              .ToArray();
```

Comment: Yes, I just ran into that exception.
So afterwards I could then just `adapterDesc.ToArray();`
This works perfectly, thank you.

I like that one line Linq!